# Query the encoding of the response object

Tags: node.js

To set the encoding of **response** object, the method **response.setEncoding()** is available. What is the method available to query the response encoding.

Tried to list all the methods supported by **response** object using the following code

```
    for (var i in proxy_response) {
        console.log(i);
    }
```

which outputs

```
_readableState
readable
domain
_events
_maxListeners
socket
connection
httpVersionMajor
httpVersionMinor
httpVersion
complete
headers
rawHeaders
trailers
rawTrailers
_pendings
_pendingIndex
upgrade
url
method
statusCode
statusMessage
client
_consuming
_dumped
req
setTimeout
read
_read
destroy
_addHeaderLines
_addHeaderLine
_dump
push
unshift
isPaused
setEncoding
pipe
unpipe
on
addListener
resume
pause
wrap
setMaxListeners
emit
once
removeListener
removeAllListeners
listeners
```

None of the methods listed seem to query the encoding type. How to query the response encoding type ?

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't afraid of relying on private properties, you can check the value of `proxy_response._readableState.encoding`.